# Has this definition of free will been discussed before? ('free will' is the ability to act against instinct)

Tags: free-will

I want to preface this by saying I'm not a 'professional' philosopher. I like to ignore pre-existing ideas to make my own route as much as I can. As such, I'm not aware of who has written papers on what topics, nor could I name more than a handful of 'famous' philosophers.

I've been interested in consciousness for years now, and I'm currently working through the idea of free will. For now, let's ignore the controversy around morality, free will, and religion completely.

The main thing I'd like to know is if the following iteration of free will has been discussed and if anyone has seriously written about it. I've tried searching in various places, but I can't find anything even tangentially related. This leads me to believe I'm either incorrect for a trivial reason or onto something interesting.

The reason that I've been considering an alternative definition to free will is because the most common definitions are unfalsifiable. My understanding of the common definition is the following: 'Humans are special because we can make decisions without being constrained to the prior state of reality'.

This asserts that we can somehow tap into a source of truth outside of reality, then make a decision that has no relation to the actual state of reality. In other words, every decision made via free will is completely irrational and unable to be scientifically measured. To be rational, you must consider the prior state of reality and come up with an appropriate solution, and a 'random' solution is the exact opposite.

On the other hand, determinists assert that free will is entirely an illusion and should be discarded as an idea. I think this is foolish because it leads to complacency - primarily due to its removal of agency from a person. I have no argument against it, I'm just not a fan of the idea due to the consequences and its lack of utility.

My 'current' definition of free will is as follows:

Axioms:

1. We assume that the true nature reality is exactly what it seems; therefore no simulation theory, and no philosophical zombies.
2. We assume that there is nothing metaphysical about humans; therefore everything that makes us special must be environmental, biological, or cultural/memetic.
3. We assume that innovation and technology more complex than fire are the results of our free will, not the causes of it.

As such,

- We (humans) like to differentiate ourselves from 'animals', despite being an animal ourselves.
- In the common culture, 'free will' is posited as the major innate distinction that separates us from animals (excluding anything physiological and metaphysical).
- Therefore, whatever is it that separates us from animals can be - to some degree - assigned to the concept of 'free will'. This will most likely include logic and memory, although I think of those as either components or extensions of free will. I suspect complex language evolved alongside free will, although it's not necessarily a prerequisite or component, given that many large animals and primates seem to have some degree of free will.

We have three major differences between animals (among countless other minor differences):

1. Our thumbs, although primates also have thumbs and are still thought of as animals; therefore I can safely ignore this.
2. Our language, although many animals have alternative ways to communicate, albeit with a less complex grammar; I will also ignore this.
3. Our ability to go against our initial instinct in pursuit of greater rewards.

I suspect that the third is a major - if not the entire - component of free will. I haven't been able to find confirmation in either direction regarding the soundness of this argument.

As a concluding thought experiment, I propose the following scenario:

Let's imagine someone lived their whole life without thinking beyond their first instinct. They would do whatever came to mind immediately, without considering the consequences. This person probably wouldn't be able to live in society, as they would immediately break some critical law the second they were able to. I'd almost assert they are little more than an animal in the shape of a human.

The consequences of this idea imply that some people are more animalistic than others and that this could be measured objectively. The thought of this makes me uncomfortable, but I can't find a fault in my reasoning.

Comment: If most humans become self-aware progressively, it would be hard to identify an "initial instinct" that we would have gone against so as to develop such a capacity for free will. That the will is free when it is (relatively) free *from* being overwhelmed by instincts is a common enough refrain; see also about [hierarchical compatibilism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/#HierComp) for considerations about being free in terms of "wanting to want."

Comment: As best as I can see you're making "frontal cortex intellectual function" a synonym for "free will". Yes?

Comment: What prevents an act against 'instinct' being determined?

Comment: Just "against instinct" is not enough, one also has to account for more insidious types of compulsion. But variants of this have been proposed and discussed to death under compatibilism, see e.g. [Frankfurt's  hierarchical compatibilism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/#HierComp) and [reasons-responsive compatibilism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compatibilism/#ReasRespComp). In both free will involves aspects of mind that supersede instincts, "higher-order" desires and rational deliberation, respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of the "separates us from animals" part of this question is... but dogs seem to be quite capable of exercising conscious veto power over their instincts.

Comment: @Futilitarian Determined acts are called spinal reflexes. They are always in line with instincts.

Comment: "We (humans) like to differentiate ourselves from 'animals', despite being an animal ourselves". No. Some people do that, others don't. Modern philosophy, biology and science in general do not do that. The question of free will is considered independent from the question of what is different between humans and other animals, and the modern approach allows various non-human animal species to have various degrees of free will.

Comment: "I'd almost assert they are little more than an animal in the shape of a human." That a pretty offensive quote, regardless of whom is targeted. People are different in intelligence, but some people trying to declare themselves "more human" than others because of intelligence seems to overlook another human quality: compassion.

Comment: Define 'instinct'. What reliable test can we propose to show which behavior is 'instinct' and which is not? Failing the availability of such a test, what evidence do we have that animals can't overcome their 'instinct'?

Comment: I'm just curious, but how does thinking of freewill as an illusion cause complacency in your opinion?  According to such theories, we _already_ dont have freewill, so is everyone already "complacent", and is that complacency even a problem if we still have a convincing illusion of freewill?

Comment: @Rusi That's essentially what I'm saying.

Comment: @Futilitarian Nothing, but I don't think the question of determinism is useful. While it's interesting to debate, whether things are predetermined is irrelevant while we live inside of the universe. It's basically like the grandfather paradox, except without time travel. If you never try to do something it'll never happen, but if you think it'll never happen you'll never try. So the only way to break the cycle is to assume it potentially could happen, regardless of whether it was predetermined.

Comment: @gs It's completely arbitrary. I just think that we should optimize for what makes us special.

Comment: @tkruse I see what you're trying to communicate with your first comment, but I'm implicitly thinking about a useful definition for laypeople - I should've specified this in the question. An academic distinction is interesting, but ultimately of minimal use outside of those spheres.

As to your second question, I don't see what makes it offensive. I intentionally didn't make any value judgements, nor did I ascribe any physical traits to the person. If we could raise a child in a jungle and then integrate them into society without problems, they should be treated the same as everyone else.

Comment: @armand I just realized I'm using instinct as a shorthand for decisions made by the oldest parts of our brain (evolutionarily) in order to pass natural selection. In other words, we could define instincts as the group of behaviours that allow an animal to survive in the natural world; ie eating, foraging, reproducing, fighting, etc. We could use this definition to define any behaviours that work against our survival as 'against instinct'. This is an interesting question that I'll need to think more about, because I can't ascribe any behaviours to this. I have a feeling this is a major flaw.

Comment: @JMac To extend my response to Futilitarian, if we assume that everything is predetermined, then it removes all agency from a person. So anything that happens to them can be waved off 'because it was always going to happen', regardless of their involvement. This is just my moral assumption, but I don't think people should live like that.

Comment: @A.Z. calling any humans potentially "animalistic" based on capabilities or behavior or anything else is offensive, even if you do not declare whom you target. This was the basis for racism, sexism, genocide, declaring other humans as non-humans. It's best if you do not try to draw a qualitative line between better and worse humans, or humans and animals. There are plenty of abilities in which other species easily surpass humans, and so little philosophic reasons to exempt humans from the animal kingdom.

Comment: if it's about the part of the brain the decision comes from, there is AFAIK no structural difference between a human brain and any other mammal brain (of course some parts of ours are much more developped, but we all have the same parts is what i mean). As such i think you will be hard pressed to find a clear delimitation between an animal and a human decision process. The good news is you are touching to something that can be studied scientifically so you minimize the risk of getting caught in endless metaphysical musing.

Answer (score 0):

“Acting against your instincts” is merely acting based on rational thought. So you would need to go one level higher: Can I act against my rational thoughts? But drug addicts for example do that a lot. So now you ask: Can I act against my involuntary impulses, caused by addiction? And so on, and so on.

In the end, there is some action that you would take if you had no free will (but if your actions were not forced). This will be what is the best action for you, based on your preferences, your knowledge of the world, and your intelligence. So can you take a different action?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, because I find your question is based on multiple fallacious assumptions, so, I take it to the basic notions.

The question behind *free will* is if we are free enough, for example, to take moral decisions, that our will can change reality (which is a metaphysical notion), that the future is not just determined by the past, but also by our decisions. If our body is just a causal mechanism that just follows a set of physical rules, there's no sin, there's no individual, there are no ethics or morals, we are just machines performing a mechanical act, even if somebody commits suicide (which is acting against his survival instinct), such act is just the consequence of the causal chain of events that the universe performs.

Of course, there's no way to prove we have free will. For that, we would need to experience two parallel and identical realities, one being different from the other due to an act of will. But we can only experience a single reality, even when modern physics tell us about the possibility of multiple realities.

In addition, you have some conceptual glitches:

> We assume that the true nature reality is exactly what it seems; therefore no simulation theory, and no philosophical zombies.

There is a circular fallacy here: free will is impossible if you set an axiom excluding any possibility of it: if objective nature is all there is, there is no subject, you negate the possibility of the subject, so, you are just a part of the natural mechanism.

> We assume that there is nothing metaphysical about humans; therefore everything that makes us special must be environmental, biological, or cultural/memetic.

"Cultural/memetic" is pure metaphysics. Or else, describe it using physics. As soon as the subject exists, ("me", who might have free will), metaphysics raises.

> We assume that innovation and technology more complex than fire are the results of our free will, not the causes of it.

No need for such boundary. The idea of technology is also metaphysical.

Think on this: free will would not be possible if Laplace's Demon is correct.

Answer (score -1):

*"The ability to act against your instincts"* is certainly a part of free will but it is too limited to be a definition.

A better definition would be *"the ability to decide one's own actions"*. That covers also the ability to follow your instincts if you want.

It also covers two more ways to distinguish us from animals:

- The ability consider alternative courses of action and choose among them
- The ability to make plans for the future